# Using Parallel.ForEach<T> to set a bool external to Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I'd like to use the power of `Parallel.ForEach` on a `List<T>` for a validation routine. The List is iterated to ensure a property is not < 1.  A bool is created that is set to false if validation finds an error which is returned in the validation method call.  I've been told that this code is problematic as bool is a primitive and not thread safe.  Is there a way I can harness of the power of `Parallel.ForEach` on a server with a lot of cores and RAM and ensure this works properly concerning thread safety?

```
public static bool IsValid(List<Airport> entities)
{
    bool isValid = true;

    Parallel.ForEach<Airport>(entities, entity =>
    {
        // userId can't be less than 1
        if (entity.userId < 1)
        {
            SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Airport {0}: invalid userId {1}", entity.airportId, entity.userId);
            isValid = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    });

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Since you only ever set it to false, I don't see how this isn't thread safe.

Comment: But wouldn't you rather Break the loop after the first error?

Comment: How big is the list?

Comment: i don't understand the synchronization issue ..
whats not thread safe here.. some thread might set it to false .. so what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with PLINQ:

```
public static bool IsValid(List<Airport> entities)
{
    return !entities.AsParallel().Any(entity => entity.UserId < 1);
}
```

However, since the part running in parallel is so small you'll get no improvement so you should stick with the regular `foreach` (or LINQ):

```
public static bool IsValid(List<Airport> entities)
{
    return !entities.Any(entity => entity.UserId < 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is big enough, I'd go with a PLINQ approach using `Enumerable.Any` or `Enumerable.All`:

```
return !entities.AsParallel().Any(x => x.UserId < 1);
```

Or

```
return entities.AsParallel().All(x => !(x.UserId < 1));
```

Usually when a pipeline style execution is used, I find PLINQ more suitable than the `Parallel` class as it removed the need to update a shared resource inside your parallel loop.

Note you should benchmark your code to make sure parallelism is worth it. In many cases, if the list isn't big enough, this may de-grade performance.